# jQuery dropdown menu hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, drop-down-menu

My problem is:

I have a drop down menu and i want that when I hover the menu the text color change and when I hover the submenu the hover state stays for both. I use this code:

```
$("ul li").hover(function () {

    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "white"}, 500);

},
function () {

    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "black"}, 400);

});

}
```

to animate the background-color on hover in menu and submenu.

I want to change the color of the text on hover to (diferent for menu and submenu, not the same color animation). For this I use this code:(Submenu example, for menu example, change the selector to $('ul.menu li a')

```
$('ul.submenu li a').hover(function () {

$(this).css({color:'#FFFFFF'});

},
function () {

$(this).css({color:'#00FF00'});

});
```

All This works fine, but when I hover the submenu the menu returns to the original color state (because the mouseleave is activated on menu hover out).

All I want is that when I hover submenu the hover state in menu stays active as well.

I've tried many things but all give me problems, only thing that works is css, but I need to control the text colors dinamically too.

**CSS That Works:**

```
ul li:hover a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

(with this css code I control the menu color with the css and when I hovered the submenu the menu stays in active state, but the submenu works with jquery .hover).

Can anyone Help? Thanks!

**HTML Menu:**

```
<ul class="menu">

      <li><a href="#">text</a></li>

      <li><a href="#">text</a>

        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>

      <li><a href="#">text</a>

</ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code an the markup for the menus?  It's difficult to get idea of what are trying to deploy.

Comment: I edit my question with Html Markup. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want hover to set the current color until you hover some other li, use classes.

css:

```
ul.submenu li a { color: #0f0; }
ul.submenu li a.hovered { color: #fff; }
```

js:

```
$('ul.submenu li a').mouseover( function() {
   if (!$(this).hasClass('hovered')) {
      $('ul.submenu li a.hovered').removeClass('hovered');
      $(this).setClass('hovered');
   }
});
```

I hope I understood you correctly.  Good luck with your project.

[edit]

Oh hm, maybe you want it so when you go off to the submenu, your parent li shouldn't lose its color, despite you mousing out.  If so, the same idea is applicable, you'd just want that mouseover code to select on the menu item mouseover (so mousing over the menu unsets all other menus and sets this one), then you just also need to have it remove your menu's class color if you mouse out of its submenu's ul.  I don't know what your menus look like structure-wise, so I can't comment on a working CSS for this selector.

Oh and finally you'd want to have a css rule vs. submenu hover to handle your submenu's highlighting.

Sorry for the rambling answer...

Comment: Hello, my hover state works for both, menu and submenu, with diferent colors and with background color animation, my only problem is when I hover a menu item, color change, if I go to submenu menu color goes back to original color, this is my problem. If I put your code only works on mouseover, i have the same problem, but Thanks !

Comment: Ah I just saw your response - I think you should be able to use $('ul.menu li').mouseout to turn off your ul.menu li a's class - that should cover the entire menu + submenu since the li contains the entire submenu.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear, you want to a)  Handle 'menu li a'.mouseover by adding the class, b) Handle submenus by adding the css hover class you wanted, and c) Handle mousing out of the menu OR submenu by capturing $('menu li').mouseout and using: $(this).children('a.hovered').removeClass('hovered')

Comment: Ok, I will try, but I don't now if I use the $('ul.menu li') selector all, menu and submenu goes back to the same color, because like you said "ul.menu li a's class - that should cover the entire menu + submenu". Thanks